# Invalid URI POP3 in Biztalk

Tags: biztalk, pop3

I'm setting up a receive location in Biztalk for POP3. 
I'm trying to obtain the attachment of emails sent to that mailbox.

I know Biztalk is processing the email because they are being deleted.

I have the same pipeline working fine in a file receive location from a folder too.
I've set all settings equal to the file receive location.

Yet I'm getting this warning when using the email receive location:

> Invalid URI: POP3:POP3://mail.server.com#user@server.com

Also if I email a file that has problems in the structure and isn't validated by the mapper I get a problem with the file structure.

> There was a failure executing the receive pipeline: "Root.Middleware.Core.Bts.Pipelines.EAIFlatFileReceive, Root.Middleware.Core.Bts.Pipelines, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=00e387b6e3fae81b" Source: "Root Flat File Process Selector" Receive Port: "ReceiveBODIVAPort" URI: "POP3://mail.server.com#user@server.com" Reason: Unexpected data found while looking for:
>       ';'

Comment: That's because the URI is invalid.  You'll see POP3: is duplicated.

Comment: @Johns-305 I don't understand what you mean with POP3: is duplicated, I only have one POP3 location or are you saying I should disable the FILE receive locations?

Comment: @Johns-305 I see what you mean now, but I think that's just part of the warning. The URI is built by biztalk based on the server name and the username. I only provide mail.server.com and user@server.com